# Clicking on 2nd box's element to expand/collapse text container, expands/collapses 1st box's text container instead - elements have same id

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, href, css-specificity

So, I've got two product boxes placed next to each other:

```
<div class="container product-box" data-toggle="collapse" href=".container-name-desc-1#info-14005" aria-expanded="true">
            <div class="product-side-content product-side-content-selected">
              <div class="product-side-content-name">Name 1</div>
              <div class="product-icon icon-arrow-down"></div>
              <div class="container-name-desc-1 text-right collapse" id="info-14005" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                <p>
                  Some very very long description of product
                </p>
                <a class="btn btn-success product-add" product-id="14005" product-price="10.45">CHOOSE</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and second

```
<div class="container product-box" data-toggle="collapse" href=".container-name-desc-2#info-14005" aria-expanded="true">
            <div class="product-side-content product-side-content-selected">
              <div class="product-side-content-name">Name 2</div>
              <div class="product-icon icon-arrow-down"></div>
              <div class="container-name-desc-2 text-right collapse" id="info-14005" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                <p>
                  Some very very long description of product
                </p>
                <a class="btn btn-success product-add" product-id="14005" product-price="10.45">CHOOSE</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

As you can see in code above, there are two classess for containers which have product description inside paragraph tag:
first is **container-name-desc-1** and second **container-name-desc-2** and both container has same id **info-14005**.
Pay attention to **href** attributes in the main container.

When I click on first product box arrow icon to expand/collapse, to show the product description, it works normally, but when I'm clicking on second product box arrow icon, the first product box description container expands/collapses again.

This is how it looks:

[image: clicked on left container's arrow and it's product description expanded]

[image: clicked on right container's arrow but left container's product description expanded again]

I think it has to do with same id name, so **info-14005**, but classess are different.

Does this mean, that browser pays attention to CSS specificity values when user specifies the href destination to some element's class/id inside, whether it's linking to child of same container or element of some other container?

In my example hrefs for both product boxes are linked to same id but different classess, so in theory clicking on one product box's arrow should expand/collapse only this particular box description container, right?

Or is this have something to do with the fact that IDs have higher specificity than classess, and last value of every href is id #info-14005, so browser somehow decides to collapse/expand only the first element which has this id assigned to itself?

I don't understand it, if anybody could answer the question?

Comment: I have a feeling it's because jQuery will target the first element it finds with that unique id. Can you not change the id's to make it compliant?

Comment: It is bad practice to have the same id more than once. If you have a look at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) you can read "The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element". I think if jQuery found an id-selector (#id) it assumes that the element is unique.

Comment: Hey @Gareth and Ben S. you might be right, because when I change those element's id's to unique, they start working properly.
But is it really the matter of id? I mean, I know that id should or even MUST be unique, but if I got non-unique id and unique classess, why it isn't working?
jQuery really does favor IDs instead of other selector types?